# React native can't find some package

Tags: javascript, npm, react-native

In a folder outside of my react native app I have placed a project I cloned from github in order to include it in my project.

I have run npm link on that project and npm linked it to my project, however when trying to run the project I get this screen

[image: react native error]

The github repository for the project is [here](https://github.com/hebcal/hebcal-js)

Answer (score 0):

All the file need to be under the root directory of the package. The packager doesnt work well if the files are outside.

A workaround described [here](https://productpains.com/post/react-native/symlink-support-for-packager/)

```
node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh --projectRoots <ROOT-1>,<ROOT2>,<ROOT-3>
```

Comment: Thank you, so I moved it inside, npm linked everything, and still the same message appears

Comment: @orelzion: Packager doesn't support symlinks so don't do `npm link`.

Comment: @oblador Oh, what should I use then?

Comment: @orelzion: Just avoid using symlinks.